# is there way to redirect unauthorised users to some custom html page in jenkins?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins

recently we enabled authentication using SSO mechanism, when unauthorised users login they are being redirected to the page where its says **Access Denied/  is missing overall read permission**.

That Particular error message is not useful at all, so wanted know is there any way where we can redirect users if they are unauthorised.

What I have tried:

Installed simple theme plugin --> created 'unauthorized.html' -->  "Manage Jenkins" --> "Configure System." --> in theme plugin configs update below java script code

```js
// JavaScript code to redirect unauthorized users to the custom error page
(function() {
    const errorPageUrl = '/unauthorized.html'; // Replace with the path to your custom error page
    const unauthorizedMessage = 'Unauthorized'; // Message shown to unauthorized users on the login page
    
    if (window.location.pathname === '/login') {
        const loginForm = document.getElementById('login');
        if (loginForm) {
            const errorMsgElement = document.createElement('div');
            errorMsgElement.className = 'error';
            errorMsgElement.textContent = unauthorizedMessage;
            loginForm.insertBefore(errorMsgElement, loginForm.firstChild);
        }
    } else if (document.body.textContent.includes('HTTP ERROR 403')) {
        window.location.href = errorPageUrl;
    }
})();
```

even then it fails with same error.

then we created Unauthorized role for which will add only Overall > Read permission.

which has two issues

1. Potential vulnerability
2. In this case we cannot catch an error in JS, all users will be authenticated without 403.